# Phaser Points from Polar Coordinates

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to update a sprite's P2 body force to equal a constant value in a given direction. With polar coordinates, that's easy: I just set the magnitude and direction to what I want. With phaser points though, the only function for setting a point's coordinates directly (Phaser.Point#set) only seems to support cartesian coordinates.

Is there an easy way to set a Phaser point to a set of polar coordinates, without having to convert from polar to cartesian coordinates myself?

Answer (score 0):

Given the unfortunate lack of a constructor for this task, use a combination of [setMagnitude()](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Point.html#setMagnitude) and [rotate()](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Point.html#rotate).  As a side, I recommend writing a utility method to do this for you so you only require a (single) simple call each time you want to instantiate a Point with polar coordinates.

```
function pointFromPolar(r, t, degrees) {
    return new Phaser.Point(1,0).setMagnitude(r).rotate(0,0,t,degrees);
}
```

`r` is magnitude, `t` is angle in radians.  If `degrees` is true, `t` is actually in degrees.

Comment: Thanks. It's been a while and I'm no longer in a position to easily test this solution, but maybe this will help someone in the future.